# How do I correctly download a map from osmnx as .svg?

Tags: python, svg, jupyter-notebook, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am new to Python. Just working with OSMnx and wanted to open a map as an svg in Illustrator. This was posted in the GitHub documentation:

**# you can also plot/save figures as SVGs to work with in Illustrator later
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_projected, save=True, file_format='svg')**

I tried it in JupyterLab and it downloaded to my files but when I open it, it is just text. How can I correctly download it and open as SVG? - Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, filepath='image.svg', save=True, show=False, close=True)
```

Run the line of code. It saves an SVG file called `image.svg`. Open that file in the SVG program of your choice (Adobe Illustrator, etc).

[edit: updated code snippet for recent OSMnx releases]

Comment: When I run this in jupyter lab I get `plot_graph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename'`. I've also tried saving using `osmnx.io.save_graph_xml`. Could you please update this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> filename='image', file_format='svg'

Use:

> filepath='image.svg'